# Using servicestack MVC integration causes: Cannot call action method 'T TryResolve[T]()' on controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, servicestack

I just made my MVC controllers inherit from `ServiceStackController`, it is the ONLY change I made and everything was working before.

I already had the following line in my `Configure()`

```
//Set MVC to use the same Funq IOC as ServiceStack
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new FunqControllerFactory(container));
```

I then tried to run and it fails on

```
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```

With:

> Cannot call action method 'T TryResolveT' on controller because
>   the action method is a generic method.

It does matter if I comment out the whole file of controller that initially causes the error, it just fails on the next.

I'll admit to just closing visual studio and doing rebuild as far as troubleshooting so far... **ServiceStack version 4.0.32**.  I'll try updating nuget packages tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes()` is looking at all public methods of a controller (inc. base methods) and treat them as actions.

To work around this I've modified the visibility on all base methods on `ServiceStackController` to `protected` [in this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/eff11c8992df78b18b07cc0137d27ea1e2d7eb47).

This change is available from **v4.0.35+** that's now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).